# How to use a series of while loops to ask questions of the user?

Tags: java, if-statement, while-loop

I want to ask three questions of the user

1. Are you happy or sad today?
2. Are you short or tall
3. Are you strong or weak

As output from the survey,  I want to display their results as a sentence with punctuation along with a single recommendation for the user (use a compound if to choose).

This is what I have so far:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {

  String reply;
  String reply2;
  String reply3;

 Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in); 
 System.out.println("Are you happy or sad today?");
  reply = scan.nextLine(); //Waits for input

  System.out.println("Are you short or tall");
    reply2 = scan.nextLine();

    System.out.println("Are you strong or weak");
    reply3 = scan.nextLine();

    if (reply.equalsIgnoreCase("Happy") && reply2.equalsIgnoreCase("Weak")&& reply3.equalsIgnoreCase("Short") ){
        System.out.println("You are a short happy person who is weak: I suggest more exercise ");

    }else if (reply.equalsIgnoreCase("sad") && reply2.equalsIgnoreCase("strong")&& reply3.equalsIgnoreCase("tall") ){
      System.out.println("You are a sad strong person who is tall: I suggest hugging a tree");

} else {
      System.out.println("Incorrect!" );
 }
}
}
```

I need help figuring out how to use a `while-loop` to ask the questions, and my code needs to be cleaned up.

POST FEEDBACK:

```
package javaapplication13;



public static void main(String[] args) {

  String reply;
  String reply2;
  String reply3;

 Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in); 
 do {
 System.out.println("Are you happy or sad today?");
  reply = scan.nextLine(); //Waits for input
 } while (!(reply.equalsIgnoreCase("happy") || reply.equalsIgnoreCase("sad")));

 do {
  System.out.println("Are you short or tall?");
    reply2 = scan.nextLine();
 } while (!(reply2.equalsIgnoreCase("short") || reply2.equalsIgnoreCase("tall")));


 do{ 
 System.out.println("Are you strong or weak");
    reply3 = scan.nextLine();
   } while (!(reply3.equalsIgnoreCase("strong") || reply3.equalsIgnoreCase("weak")));


 if (reply.equalsIgnoreCase("Happy") && reply2.equalsIgnoreCase("short")&& reply3.equalsIgnoreCase("weak") ){
        System.out.println("You are a short happy person who is weak: I suggest more exercise! ");


 } else if (reply.equalsIgnoreCase("sad") && reply2.equalsIgnoreCase("tall")&& reply3.equalsIgnoreCase("strong") ){
      System.out.println("You are a sad strong person who is tall: I suggest hugging a tree!");

      } else if (reply.equalsIgnoreCase("sad") && reply2.equalsIgnoreCase("short")&& reply3.equalsIgnoreCase("weak") ){
      System.out.println("You are a sad short person who is weak: I am sorry to hear that");





 }
}
```

}

Comment: Welcome to SO! To do this in a while loop, you'll need a "counter" variable (usually i) that starts at 1 and increments each iteration. For each iteration of the loop, if i=1 then ask the first question, if i=2 then ask the 2nd question, if i=3 then ask the 3rd question. Then store each response in their own variable depending on which question was asked (reply, reply2, reply3). Then after the loop, compile your sentence using the gathered responses. Give the while loop a try and post your new code if you need more help

Comment: There are more combinations of the answers that your code consider: **[happy, strong, tall], [happy, strong, short], [happy, weak, tall], [happy, weak, short], [sad, strong, tall],.. etc.**. It isn't clear what would be your suggestions for all the combinations. BTW, it's easy to ask the questions one by one and print the result in one statement...

Comment: Also, what determines the "I suggest" comment at the end? See @zlakad's comment above, just what I was going to ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have already figured out how to use while-loops,
adding 3 boolean variables into your code that represent emotion, height, and strength will clean up the code a bit.

```
    boolean emotion;
    boolean height;
    boolean strength;
```

In do-while loop, if reply matches "Happy" set the boolean value to true, else, set it to false which is obviously going to be "sad". Same for the other 2 questions.

```
do {
        System.out.println("Are you happy or sad today?");
        reply = scan.nextLine(); // Waits for input
        if (reply.equalsIgnoreCase("Happy")) {
            emotion = true;
        } else {
            emotion = false;
        }
    } while (!(reply.equalsIgnoreCase("happy") || reply.equalsIgnoreCase("sad")));

    do {
        System.out.println("Are you short or tall?");
        reply2 = scan.nextLine();
        if (reply.equalsIgnoreCase("Tall")) {
            height = true;
        } else {
            height = false;
        }
    } while (!(reply2.equalsIgnoreCase("short") || reply2.equalsIgnoreCase("tall")));

    do {
        System.out.println("Are you strong or weak");
        reply3 = scan.nextLine();
        if (reply.equalsIgnoreCase("Strong")) {
            strength = true;
        } else {
            strength = false;
        }
    } while (!(reply3.equalsIgnoreCase("strong") || reply3.equalsIgnoreCase("weak")))
```

Then, when it comes to last part where you have to consider combinations of 3 answers,
instead of having to write a long code like

```
if(reply.equalsIgnoreCase("Happy") && reply2.equalsIgnoreCase("short")&& reply3.equalsIgnoreCase("weak"))
```

you could simply check the boolean values to determine your suggestion.

```
if (emotion && !height && !strength) {
        System.out.println("You are a short happy person who is weak: I suggest more exercise! ");

    } else if (!emotion&&strength&&height) {
        System.out.println("You are a sad strong person who is tall: I suggest hugging a tree!");

    } else if (!emotion&&!height&&!strength) {
        System.out.println("You are a sad short person who is weak: I am sorry to hear that");

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

To make it easy for maintenance, better make use of java collections.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.TreeMap;

public class Survey {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<String> questions = Arrays.asList("Are you happy or sad today?", "Are you short or tall?", "Are you strong or weak");
        List<Set<String> > answers = Arrays.asList(new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList("happy", "sad")),
                new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList("short", "tall")),
                new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList("strong", "weak"))
        );
        List<String> replies = new ArrayList<String>();
        Map<String, String> conclusions = new TreeMap<String, String>();
        conclusions.put("[happy, short, weak]", "You are a short happy person who is weak: I suggest more exercise! ");
        conclusions.put("[sad, tall, strong]", "You are a sad strong person who is tall: I suggest hugging a tree!");
        conclusions.put("[sad, short, weak]", "You are a sad short person who is weak: I am sorry to hear that");

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in); 
        do {
            int questionNo = replies.size();
            System.out.println(questions.get(questionNo));
            String reply = scan.nextLine().toLowerCase(); //Waits for input
            if(answers.get(questionNo).contains(reply))
                replies.add(reply);

        } while (replies.size() < questions.size());

        String conclusion = conclusions.get(replies.toString());
        if (conclusion != null){
            System.out.println(conclusion);
        }
        scan.close();
    }

}
```